# I need help with possessives: should this be [center + noun] or [center's + noun]?

Tags: possessives

At the beginning of the school year, students are required to take measures that will include the standard University Center’s assessment battery.

Should it be **Center's** or **Center**?

Answer (score 2):

Either can work. Both forms convey essentially the same information.

With the possessive, the phrase is understood in the straightforward manner: it's the *assessment battery* related to (owned by / administered by / etc) the *University Center*.

Without the possessive, it makes *University Center* an attributive noun.

> In grammar, a noun adjunct or attributive noun or noun (pre)modifier is an optional noun that modifies another noun; it is a noun functioning as a pre-modifier in a noun phrase. For example, in the phrase "chicken soup" the noun adjunct "chicken" modifies the noun "soup".
>   [- wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct)