# Hospital's staff or hospital staff?

Tags: grammar

Is the apostrophe in the second sentence viable?

> The hospital staff are extremely busy.
> The hospital's staff are extremely busy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I need help with possessives: should this be \[center + noun\] or \[center's + noun\]?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/427488/i-need-help-with-possessives-should-this-be-center-noun-or-centers-noun) Either is allowed. You can also read [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30385/can-one-explain-the-different-distributions-of-the-saxon-and-the-analytic-norma) about using 's with inanimate objects.

Comment: In normal speech, there is probably no discernable difference.

Comment: The possessive **must** refer to the staff at a definite hospital, specified or otherwise in the hearer's mind. The attributive usage allows for both this, and staff at various hospitals considered together. It would also be used in say 'We get a lot of police, teachers and hospital workers calling in for a coffee. The hospital staff are extremely busy at the moment because of Covid.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Interesting use of **call in**, to my AmEar.  We do say "to call on a friend" when referring to a friendly visit but don't use the verb **call**  when we "visit" a coffee shop.

Comment: @Tim Common in the UK for 'pay a swift visit [to] Over 100 000 hits for "call in at the supermarket". With 'on', only used for people, but with 'at', available for shops, the bank, the garage [service station], the library, the recycling centre ....

Comment: @Tim maybe they're placing an order by phone.

Comment: @phoog: Or shouting in their coffee orders from the sidewalk, since it was during COVID  ;-)   One super-sized caramel oat-milk latte!